# ServiceStack: How to get the IHttpRequest object from within a ServiceExceptionHandler in my AppHost?

Tags: c#, servicestack

Looks like only the request dto and the exception objects are available for use within the ServiceExceptionHandler of the AppHost. I need access to the IHttpRequest object so I can access the Items collection and get at my request context's metadata.

Comment: You can use the `ExceptionHandler` handler where you can supply a delegate with the following signature `this.ExceptionHandler = (req, res, operationName, ex) => { }` where `ExceptionHandler` is a  `public delegate void HandleUncaughtExceptionDelegate(
        IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, string operationName, Exception ex);`

Comment: That catches non-service related exceptions. You're right in that it has the parameters I need, but it's not available for service-level exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agreed. It's not currently available, but [I've just checked this into v3](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/cb0929573b8abc653120688bc6ff9bfa07f961fe) and master branches. It will be available on NuGet after this weekend's release of v3.9.64+.

I'm generally reluctant to add breaking changes, but it should only be localized to 1 place so it shouldn't be too disruptive and as you've described having access to `IHttpRequest` is useful.

Comment: mythz, ServiceStack.Interfaces (in ServiceStack.Common) doesn't look versioned correctly. It's 1.0.0.0 while all other assemblies in this 3.9.64 release are 3.9.64.0